# How to write constructor where the types are from another class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

I'm doing a UML diagram for a *Connect four* game. It is a two-player connection board game, in which the players choose a color and then take turns dropping colored discs into a seven-column, six-row vertically suspended grid.

I have a problem with the UML Diagram. The class game has 2 variables that came from another class(is this ok?). And secondly how is possible to write the constructor for all the given variables?

Notice:The purpose of UML Diagram is not to write code out of it, but only as a project. There are no requirements.

[image: UML Connect four]

Comment: Having an instance of a class in another class is ok, but you must check not having circular dependency. Class A need B and class B needs A.

Comment: Please can you say this in depency with my example.You mean that Player should not have a connection with Board?@SeyedMohammadAminAtyabi

Comment: I see no problem for creating an instance of Game. First you instantiate Player. Then using this instance you instantiate Gameboard. After that using both instances you can instantiate Game.

Comment: Just asking one last thing,do you think that this UML is ok?Does it have any mistake(except circular dependency)?Is there any more method that I should include?@SeyedMohammadAminAtyabi

Comment: Well I don't know this game but I see some methods that can be removed. For example in class Gameboard there are two methods redWind and blueWin. This can be simplified as getWinner.

Comment: Game is Connect four.is a two-player connection board game, in which the players choose a color and then take turns dropping colored discs into a seven-column, six-row vertically suspended grid. The pieces fall straight down, occupying the lowest available space within the column. The objective of the game is to be the first to form a horizontal, vertical, or diagonal line of four of one's own discs.Any suggestions please?

Comment: Seems ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Classes with properties of other types

Let's take the example of `Game` and `Player`.  In your diagram,  you show a property `playernames: Player[]`.  This means that the class `Game` is implicitly associated with the class `Player`.  At the same time you show an explicit association with the `Player` class.  This is ambiguous: are both implicit and explicit associations the same ? Or are these two different associations?

A less ambiguous representation is to remove the property from the compartment of the class, and show its visibility and name as a role on the association line at the opposite end.

Another example is the class' `Game`  property `board:Board`.  At the same time, there is an association to a `Gameboard`. Are these two the same, and there is a mistake in one of the class name? Or did you forget a `«interface» Board` in your diagram, to which `Game` should be associated and that `Gameboard` would implement ? Up to you to clarify.

If possible,  indicate the multiplicity of the associations.  If it's exactly 1, or exactly 2, write it down.  If it's several write a `*`.

### Constructors

In UML, a constructor is an operator like any other. It could have any name and should return a type corresponding to the owning class. It should be preceded by the stereotype `«Create»`:

```
+ «Create» Game():Game
```

In your class you also have a related operations (remark: in UML an operation that does not return anything does not return `void`, but nothing at all):

```
+ initialize() 
+ setBoard (board: Board)
```

The reader can infer that the board is created elsewhere and probably needs to be set.  It is however not specified in your diagram which of the constructor or the initializer creates/constructs the other objects for the remaining propertiers. If this matters for you, you could add a comment note in plaintext. If you'd prefer a more formal way,  you could express a post-condition instead.

If `Game` does not create some of its properties, for example, if your user interface would create `Player`  objects that would then be passed to the constructor,  you'd indicate these objects in your operation specifications, in the same way than in Java:

```
+ «Create» Game(player: Player[2]):Game
```

But if you set the board, you could also set (or add) the players.

### Unrelated remarks

- Several `Game` operations return `Person` but there is no class like this. (You could add such a class in your diagram and draw a dependency).
- The name of the property `playernames` is misleading:  it's players, and players are not just the names.  It's also the points, the state, annd everything that makes a player.
- can you explain why you've put arrows on the associations ?  If not, it's probably better to remove them.
- `Extends` is not an UML keyword.  Just remove it: the specialization that you have drawn is sufficient:  it means inheritance.  For intertaces that are implemented you'd use the same symbol but with a dashed line.

Comment: `Game` uses `Board` as a attribute. It should (probably) rather be a role `board` towards `Gameboard`. Anyhow it looks as being wrong. Regarding `Extends `
: it would just be the name of an arbitrary Generalization. It's not wrong, but just confusing and meaningless.

Comment: @qwerty_so Yes, this looks like a mismatch in the class names. If this is confirmed, the use of a `+board` role would definitively be the less ambiguous way to go. I could also well imagine the interface approach, with board being a role of that interface that would be  realized by Gameboard.

Comment: FWIW: The UML 2.5 spec uses «Create» (upper case C); see p. 678. I know the EA ignores the case of stereotypes (but not always). Anyhow, you should use it likes specified.

Comment: @qwerty_so ok, I'll capitalize. But only because the lowercase is stylistically obsolete, as p.262 tells us:  "*Matching between the names of Stereotype definitions and applications is case-insensitive, so **naming stereotype applications with lower-case letters where the stereotypes are defined using uppercase letters is valid**, although stylistically obsolete. For legacy reasons a tool may display stereotype names with the initial letter in lower case even when defined in upper case.*" - I don't want to promote bad habits ;-)

Comment: We just want to see proper answers here ;-)

Comment: A constructor in Java is the method that is called to initialize an instance when it is created by the `new` operator. A Java constructor does not create a new instance, because an instance cannot create itself. A Java constructor does not return anything. Unfortunately, the word constructor in UML has a different definition: "an Operation having a single return result parameter of the type of the owning Class" (UML 2.5 section 11.4.4). Such an operation gets the «Create» stereotype. Because Java constructors are not UML constructors, they shall not have the «Create» stereotype.